# discord api on guild info Unauthorized

Tags: javascript, html, api, discord, discord.js

in Postman
my url is `https://discordapp.com/api/v6/guilds/417208237142573056`

and i got guild id from `https://discordapp.com/api/v6/users/@me/guilds` ->list all guild ids

my header is setup perfectly since i am getting result for `/users/@me/guilds`

still it is `authorization : Bearer n*****************a7`

its giving me `{"message": "401: Unauthorized", "code": 0}`

i got my token `https://discord.com/api/oauth2/authorize?client_id=5*******4&redirect_uri=http********8000%2Fcallback.html&response_type=token&scope=identify%20guilds` -> tried resonse type `code` as well

scopes are `identify` and `guilds`

so where am i doing it wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't get that info at this time or to simply put at this time it's not available in oth2 api